# Load an HTML file directly from public folder as View in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel.
I'm trying to put together my own wedding invitation.
I have a folder in my public folder, will styles, and scripts for it.

I'm wondering if I can point to that folder, instead of copy-and-paste everything into a new blade file.

---

**Route**

`Route::get('/wedding', 'WeddingController@index');`

---

**WeddingController**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class WeddingController extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        return view('wedding.index');
    }

}
```

---

**Question**

I'm wondering if I can point my index function to load the `index.html` from one of my folder in my **/public** folder.

Do we have to load the `.blade` file from the `app/resources/views` directory ?

Any helps / suggestions on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: If there is a file located at `public/wedding/index.html`, then when you go to `http://localhost/wedding` it will show the contents of `index.html` without ever invoking Laravel. No routes or controllers needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just place the wedding folder directly inside the public folder:

```
mv wedding/ /path/to/laravel/public
```

Then visit your site URL with a wedding suffix:

```
http://my-site.com/wedding
```

This will load the `index.html` from inside the wedding folder.

This works via Nginx's `try_files` directive in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site` config file:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This instructs Nginx to first search for an actual file corresponding to the URL (for example, `/css/app.css`, `/wedding/index.html`, etc). If it does not find a matching file (e.g. it would normally return a 404 not found), then it should instead pass the query string as an argument to the index.php script.

Comment: How comes I dont have to register for that route ? Can you elaborate that a little bit ?

Comment: I really like this solution. I can't believe I made it harder than it is.

Comment: I saw. Thank-you so much for this. I'll make sure to accept it real soon.

Comment: I noticed, this doesn't work on local. Only work on the server. Do you know why ?

Comment: Are you using Nginx or something else locally?

Comment: I used MAMP. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Strange; Laravel comes with a .htaccess file to tell Apache to work the same way as Nginx's try_files directive, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work. You may need to post a separate question about that.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me the url? Have a look.

Comment: I'm just curious. When it comes to the safety of my website, Is this a safe thing to do?

Answer (score 7):

Load static files from controller using `File` Facade

```
use File;

return File::get(public_path() . '/to new folder name/index.html');
```

Comment: That is not what I was asking.

Comment: I know how to load file. It's easy.

Comment: For laravel 5.6 `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to rename your wedding invitation's `index.html` to `index.php` and place it within your `resources/views` folder, so that it becomes a Laravel template.

```
cd path/to/laravel
mkdir resources/views/wedding
mv public/wedding/index.html resources/views/wedding/index.php
```

Then you can call it from your controller as you wish:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('wedding.index');
}
```

Of course with this method you'll have to ensure any CSS/JavaScript/image urls are properly mapped to their respective locations within the `public/` folder.

Comment: This solution only work, when you rename `index.html` --> `index.blade.php`